# I'm installing ubuntu but stuck

Tags: installation

I've partitioned by hard drive, does that mean I have to put the program on my usb or cd whichever I choose. The instructions I was looking at about partitioning just ended so I'm not sure what to do after this.

Answer (score 0):

Literally one google search away is your answer.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest